# Finding connected subsets in database tables

Tags: sql, duplicates

In my table I have some records that match with another :

```
644432 738987
738987 644432
..
854313 871860
854313 874411
871860 854313
871860 874411
874411 854313
874411 871860
```

For example `644432` matches with `738987` and `738987` matches with `644432` (obviously).
For me they must be the same and I must get one and only one (644432 or 738987 whatever).

another example `854313` matches with `871860` which matches with `874411` (that's why I have 6 records for them).

I must get only two records in final, how can I do that?

Sorry for my english and thanks to tell me if my question is not clear.

For the example there's a code to populate a table to do for example :

```
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (ColA  INT, ColB  INT)
insert into @DataTable  values 
(644432,    738987),
(738987,    644432),
(854313,    871860),
(854313,    874411),
(871860,    854313),
(871860,    874411),
(874411,    854313),
(874411,    871860)
select * from @DataTable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: If you have a choice, which record do you want?

Comment: There is no choice, I want just get one in every group and go to lunch :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to isolate "clusters" of "connected" records, and report one result for every cluster found? BTW there is a loop in the second cluster, which will make recursive solutions harder.

Comment: Yes recursive will be harder :)
Thanks for your comments guys, i will try the Stony' solution and keep you in touch.

Comment: Please include the desired result based on the data already given. Based on your logic, I get more than 2 records in final.

Comment: Exactly tombom. Me too I get more than 2 results, sorry for my comment but <br> not include in the code

Comment: I don't think we fully understand your rules for what is considered a match.

Comment: OK i will re-explain : the records 644432 and 738987 have something in common >> that's wy a previous code gives two records. 
871860, 854313 and 874411 have something inn common too, and that's why we have 6 records, i want just (644432 or 738987) in the first case and (871860 or 854313 or 874411) >> so 2 records as a result, one in every group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the example below will follow links that are one level deep. This could be cleaned up massively with a stored procedure or creating the query from code of course, which would make it easier to add additional levels of link following.

```
-- Set up an example table
create table DataTable
(
    A int,
    B int
)
GO

insert into DataTable values(644432,738987)
insert into DataTable values(738987,644432)
insert into DataTable values(854313,871860)
insert into DataTable values(854313,874411)
insert into DataTable values(871860,854313)
insert into DataTable values(871860,874411)
insert into DataTable values(874411,854313)
insert into DataTable values(874411,871860)
GO

-- Strip out initial duplicates
select distinct A,B into Pass1
from
(
  select case when A > B then B else A end as A,
  case when A > B then A else B end as B
  from DataTable
) minmax

-- Create a copy that we will update with links between values
select * into Pass2 from Pass1 order by A

update Pass2 set B=x.NewB from
(
  select L.A as OldA,L.B as OldB, R.B as NewB
  from Pass1 L
  inner join Pass1 R on L.B = R.A
) x
where Pass2.A=x.OldA and Pass2.B=x.OldB

update Pass2 set A=x.NewA from
(
  select L.B as OldA, R.B as OldB, L.A as NewA
  from Pass1 L
  inner join Pass1 R on L.B = R.A
) x
where Pass2.A=x.OldA and Pass2.B=x.OldB

-- Dedupe any newly created duplicates
select distinct A,B
from
(
  select case when A > B then B else A end as A,
  case when A > B then A else B end as B
  from Pass2
) minmax
```

Comment: This is LEGEN -wait for it- DARY!!! Thanks a lot for you Stony and thanx for all other :)

Comment: Thanks! What I meant by 1 level of linking is that if you do 1 2, 2 3, 3 4, 4 5 it won't work fully.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a table called DataTable with two columns, ColA and ColB, then you could do:

```
select distinct Smallest,Largest from
(
  select case when ColA > ColB then ColB else ColA end as Smallest,
  case when ColA > ColB then ColA else colB end as Largest
  from DataTable
) minmax
```

This uses an inner select to rearrange the values so that the smallest value is always the first column and the largest value is in the second column. Then the outer select just pulls out the distinct set of values.

Comment: For the first group it works but not for the second group of records :<br> I get this result : <br> Smallest Largest 644432 738987 >> Good because (738987 644432) was deleted 854313 871860 >> 1/3 854313 874411 >> 2/3 871860 874411 >> 3/3 I want one of 1/3 or 2/3 or 3/3 :)

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote will only identify direct duplicates, it won't do the more complicated second type of match.

Comment: OK don't be sorry, i will re-explain : the records 644432 and 738987 have something in common >> that's why a previous code gives two records. 871860, 854313 and 874411 have something inn common too, and that's why we have 6 records, i want just (644432 or 738987) in the first case and (871860 or 854313 or 874411) >> so 2 records as a result, one in every group.

Comment: I added a new answer that works when you only have to follow one level of linking between numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stony it works for me, even I don't understund a lot "you only have to follow one level of linking between numbers"... But it works and data all are the same that I gave in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

select col1,col2 from (Select col1+col2 as indicator, col1, col2 from table1) 
a  group by indicator

[Refer sqlfiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b04e/10)

Note : This will not work if the sum is same for two different rows.

Comment: Invalid column name : 'indicator'. :)
However +1 for "Choose a job you love, and you will never have to work a day in your life"

Comment: @user2190624 Thanks for comment. Changed group by.

Comment: Still not working :) I added a code in the question field to have an exemple.

Comment: Thanx for reply : 

Execute the code ans see :) >> Change @@ by one 
DECLARE @@DataTable TABLE (ColA INT, ColB INT)
insert into @DataTable values
(644432, 738987),
(738987, 644432),
(854313, 871860),
(854313, 874411),
(871860, 854313),
(871860, 874411),
(874411, 854313),
(874411, 871860)
select * from @@DataTable

select ColA,ColB from (Select ColA+ColB as indicator, ColA, ColB from @@DataTable) a group by indicator

Comment: @user2190624 Executed successfully. [see here for sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/900ef/5). which database are you using? I executed for Mysql

Comment: I think this will not working because you will always 4 results, i must have 2

Answer (score 0):

```
select n1,n2 from(select a.col1 col1,a.col2 col2,rownum rn from tbl a, tbl b 
where a.col1||a.col2=(b.col2||b.col1)) where mod(rn,2)<>0
union
select a.col1 col1,a.col2 col2 from tbl a left outer join tbl b on 
a.col1||a.col2=(b.col2||b.col1) where b.col1 is null
```

Comment: NOt working unfortunately for me, I added a code in the question field to have an exemple.

Comment: I tried the same query for your data specified ...
It is running fine for me .

BTW which RDBMS are you using 
The above query will work fine in Oracle

Comment: Sql Server 2008, and you get two rows as a result ?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive query for finding the connected sets. For every chain the item with the lowest number is reported as a "group leader".

The query works fy first ordering the members of the pairs, and then finding the chains of connected components. This method will *not* work if there are multiple starting points for a cluster. (But it does avoid loops)

This syntax is for Postgresql, for microsoft you should omit the `RECURSIVE` keyword, and for Oracle you should use `CONNECT BY, PRIOR`. YMMV.

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE pairs (ONE INTEGER NOT NULL, two INTEGER NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (one, two)
        );
INSERT INTO pairs(one, two) values
(644432,738987) ,(738987,644432)
,(854313,871860) ,(854313,874411) ,(871860,854313) ,(871860,874411) ,(874411,854313) ,(874411,871860)
        ;

WITH RECURSIVE rope AS (
        WITH opair AS (
                SELECT LEAST(one, two) AS one
                , GREATEST(one, two) AS two
                FROM pairs
                )
        SELECT o.one AS top
        , o.one AS one
        , o.two AS two
        FROM opair o
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM opair x WHERE x.two=o.one)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT k.one AS top
        , p.one AS one
        , p.two AS two
        FROM opair p
        JOIN rope k ON k.two = p.one
        )
SELECT DISTINCT top
        , COUNT(*) AS N_members
FROM rope
GROUP BY top
ORDER BY top
        ;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 8
  top   | n_members 
--------+-----------
 644432 |         2
 854313 |         8
(2 rows)
```

Comment: this is the result that I want BUT I work in SQL Server 2008 R2, if only I can tell to my boss to change it now :) I'm trying to understund the allgorithm you used.

Comment: As I said, for microsoft you should remove the `recursive` keyword. ((Maybe a few other minor changes, too.)

Comment: Yes because of the result i ommit to read all the answer :) sorry, Ok i will try to do that changes, I hope it will work :) thanks

Comment: Can't translate that to microsoft